# How to declare class that extends generic that extends generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that extends generic class that also extends (another) generic class.

```
class B<TypeB> extends C{}
class C<TypeC>{}
```

and now my problems is how to specify the TypeC when creating class A
should be something like:

```
class A extends B<Type1><C<Type2>>
```

but the above actually does not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your decl of `B` should be:

```
class B<TB, TC> extends C<TC> {
}
```

and your target will be

```
class A extends B<ConcreteB, ConcreteC> {
}
```

Comment: 10x, seems quite natural actually

Comment: One thing you should be cautious of is if your C class is actually something like C<F extends Foo>, and you define B as B<TB, TC> extends C<TC> (Where TC extends Foo, in this case), if you have an untyped B floating around (Like a method that returns B instead of B<TB, TC>), you'll lose the TC information on C. If C had a method that returned F, instead of returning TC, as generics would imply here, Java can only figure out that you're returning a F (On b.getFoo() )